# Can't get exif data from multiple files before upload

Tags: jquery, image, upload, image-uploading, exif

I'm trying to get exif data from multiple file's at once before any kind of upload. I'm using:

https://github.com/sanisoft/jQuery-fileExif

```
var someCallback = function(exifObject) 
{
    console.log(exifObject);
}   

$('#file-input').change(function(e) 
{
    files = event.target.files;

    for(var i = 0, len = files.length; i < len; i++) 
    {
        var file = files[i];

        $(this).fileExif(someCallback);
        console.log(file);
    }            
});
```

But every time I'm getting same duplicated exif data from just one single file (doesn't matter how many files are uploaded) in my console. If I change:

```
 $(file).fileExif(someCallback);
```

I'm getting:

```
 TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined
```

My knowlage of jQuery and JS is very limited... Please, can someone help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

In the `jquery.exif.js`

replace the code for `$.fn.fileExif` with this code

```
$.fn.fileExif = function(callback) {

    for(var i = 0 ;i < this[0].files.length;i++){

        var reader = new FileReader();

        reader.onload = function(event) {

            var content = event.target.result;

            var binaryResponse = new BinaryFile(content);

            callback(EXIF.readFromBinaryFile(binaryResponse));
        };

        reader.readAsBinaryString(getFilePart(this[0].files[i]));
     }
};
```